# Thanks to all of our community members!

Tags: discussion

It's the end of the year and I believe it's a good time to remember what was done during the year and thank the people who help make IPS such a great place.

So please, use the answers below to thank every person you believe did something great for this community during this year.

Here are a few (non-exhaustive) examples:

- Someone posted a great question/answer
- Someone asked a very important meta question
- Someone posted a very well explained meta answer
- Someone made a great edit
- Someone was very helpful in the way they commented
- Etc..

---

**Note**: I am planning to post such an answer myself, but I don't have the time right now. But don't worry, I have a lots of thanks in here for you :)

In any way, **happy end of the year for all of you!**

Answer (score 8):

*Avazula*:

- You are the most loving and caring person I know. This year, you became a mod and I would like to thank you for all the work you have done as such so far. I love you and I hope you will stay with us for a long time again.

*Scohe*:

- **A lot** of thanks for all the work you are doing with the comment bot. Your new features are amazing and the cats were definitively missing! I would also thank you for all the other work you are doing for the community but, really, what you are doing with the bot is so amazing that the rest is nothing in comparison.

*EmC*:

- When it comes to leaving comments, to my eyes, you are always the one making the nicest one. I definitively admire you for that.

*Tinkeringbell*:

- You always explain IPS policy very well. When there is a meta question about that, I'm always waiting for your answer. And I will be always grateful for how well you explained everything to me when I first arrived.

*Rainbacon*:

- You are a friend and a very active member of this community. It's always nice to compete with you for "who will gain the most rep this year". I hope we will both keep being as active and push each other to be always better.

*AJ*:

- You are a mod and help make this place a safe one. Thank you for that. Also, please, never stop posting your jokes in chat!

*Upper_Case*:

- You and I don't always agree, but you always ask very interesting meta question and I'm thankful that you do. Please, keep doing it (even if it's to disagree with me :p )

*OldPadawan*:

- You are not a chat regular and, thus, I don't know you very well. But you are always helping moderate this site, so thank you.

The lgbt+ tag:

- I would like to give a special thanks to all the people who are asking and answering lgbt+ questions. I believe that it is an important topic and I'm very glad were are able to ask and answer (interpersonal) questions about it here.

There is a lot of other people I wish I could talk about. Especially you, all the chat regulars. I love you all. Please, keep being so chatty and nice!

Comment: Thanks for being in your list, really appreciate it :)) and you're right about chat, it's not my cup o'tea. At all (to say the least). So I'd rather use my very few minutes each time to check the Q/A/c ('c' for comments), makes me feel more "*on duty and useful*". Happy New Year to ya'll.

Comment: *blushes* - thank you for the kind words, and happy new year to you too!!